# python3.5 format number and align in one line

Tags: python, format, alignment, python-3.5, number-formatting

Is there a way to combine number formatting and aligning in the same format line?

for example, I'm trying to show a percentage with only 2 decimals and align to the right in a given space. The two lines approach works fine:

```
value = '{:05.2f}%'.format(3.141592653589793)
print('{:>{width}}'.format(value, width=20))
```

But is there a way to do it in one line? something like this:

```
print('{:05.2f>{width}}%'.format(3.141592653589793, width=20))
```

Comment: Well you could do `'{:05.2f}%'.format(3.141592653589793).rjust(20)`

Comment: @vaultah would the work in the case I want to show more then one value in the same line? like:

Results(%)       12.05%       25.02%      30.25%

Comment: @AngelGris: Depends on what you would want that to do; how would you solve it using multiple lines?

Comment: @ScottHunter in multilpe lines it would format each number in one line and then use all those formated numbers in the last line. Kind of the example I included in the question, but with more "value" variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers the letter, if not the spirit, of the question:

```
print('{:>{width}}'.format('{:05.2f}%'.format(3.141592653589793), width=20))
```

Comment: Actually solves the problem in one line, but what I'm trying to find out is if it's possible to combine more than 1 formatting option within the same brackets. Thanks.